# Hypergraph variant of handshake problem.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, hypergraphs

I came across this well known problem that goes something like this.

> If $n$ people shake hands with each other. How many handshakes will be there in total?

The question can be interpreted as asking about the number of edges in a complete graph of with $n$ vertices, which will be $n \choose 2 $.

What if the question was changed to something more tricky?

> If $n$ people take turns playing board games with each other. Each game needs exactly $k$ players to play. How many games are needed for everyone to have played a game with everyone else?

As you can see, for the case of $k=2$ this would be equivalent to the previous handshake problem.

I initially thought the answer would be $ n \choose k$, but in the case of $n = 6$ and $ k= 4$ , I can make everyone play everyone with just 3 games.

If the players are labeled $[1 .. n]$

$$ \text{Game 1: } {1,2,3,4} \\\text{Game 2: } {3,4,5,6} \\\text{Game 3: } {1,2,5,6} $$

Since $ {6 \choose 4} \neq 3 $, this cannot be the answer. The binomial is counting all possible games even when getting everyone to play each is possible with less games.

I suspect that considering the games as hyperedges of k-uniform hypergraph is the best way to approach this problem, but I lack any formal math training beyond high-school math, so I don't know where to start. I've tried doing some googling (which is how I know what a hypergraph is), but I've haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692833/collection-of-subset-generating-every-pairs-of-elements

Answer (score 1):

Every game makes $\binom k2$ associations of players, and we need to cover all $\binom n2$ pairs of players, so a lower bound for the number of games is $\left\lceil\binom n2\big/\binom k2\right\rceil$. In your example case, $\left\lceil\binom 62\big/\binom 42\right\rceil = \lceil 15/6\rceil = 3$ so you have found the minimum.

However this minimum may not always be achievable. It's relatively straightforward to demonstrate that 10 people playing 6-player games cannot all experience all game partners within only 3 games, despite the lower bound $\left\lceil\binom {10}2\big/\binom 62\right\rceil = \lceil 45/15\rceil = 3$.

Comment: So there isn't any way to get the true minimum number of games besides brute force?

Comment: @Bejofo There is probably also an upper limit on the "true minimum" - I'd have to think about that - but between these two (in most cases) I would expect a bit of a search. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3692882/206402) there is a special case but it would be rare.